# Detail page uid mandatory in Typo3 9.5 seo sitemap for own extension?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I am trying to set up my sitemap in Typo3 9.5 and it worked well for regular pages and news. For my own plugin, I don't want to specify a detail page because the list and detail pages are the same pages. I've tried setting `url.pageId = 0` and mapping the `pid` of `myobject` to the `id` in `fieldToParameterMap`, but the line is ignored (mapping 'foo' works just fine, `id` is probably not allowed). How can i set the list page `pid` as the detail page `pid`?

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    config {
        xmlSitemap {
            sitemaps {
                pages { 
                    provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\PagesXmlSitemapDataProvider
                    config {
                        additionalWhere = AND no_index = 0
                    }
                }
                myextension {
                    provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider
                    config {
                        table = tx_myextension_domain_model_myobject
                        sortField = objectname
                        lastModifiedField = tstamp
                        additionalWhere = AND (deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0)
                        pid = 1
                        recursive = 5
                        url {
                            pageId = /*** uid of detail view page expected ***/
                            fieldToParameterMap {
                                pid = id
                                uid = tx_myextension_display[myobject]
                            }
                            additionalGetParameters {
                                tx_myextension_display.controller = Mycontroller
                                tx_myextension_display.action = show
                            }
                            useCacheHash = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kind regards,

Moritz

Comment: A page ID is necessary. Your records must be shown at any kind of detail-view. This can be a page that switches between list/detail view. But where should TYPO3/the sitemap link to with the only knowledge about the record, but without information about where it can be displayed?
pageId should be a page where your plugin can display the detail view.

Comment: the `pid` of `myobject` is the page where the detail view should be displayed, hence my attempt `pid = id` in `fieldToParameterMap`. My object records are on multiple pages.

Comment: No, that won't work. The target pageId is `...config.url.pageId`(see \TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider::defineUrl()) - with fallback to the current page.
Maybe, you can define multiple sections, if there are not too many different detail pages. In combination with a matching where-clause, you should get a complete sitemap without duplicates.

Comment: Ok, too bad. thanks for your answers! If i set up multiple sitemaps for my extension, it'd be about 15 separate. If google is ok with it, then i am, too. But i might look into an own DataProvider.